# vue-test-utils | TypeError: s.split is not a function

Tags: vue.js, split, vue-test-utils

I try to run a test with `vue-test-utils`, including a component that has a mixin included, which has a function using `split()` on a string. The test looks like this:

```
describe('adminExample.vue Test', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(adminExample, {
        global: {
            mixins: [globalHelpers, authGatewayForElements, storeService],
            plugins: [store]
        }
    })
    it('renders component and is named properly', () => {
        // check the name of the component
        expect(wrapper.vm.$options.name).toMatch('adminExample')
    })
})
```

`adminExample.vue` doesn't give any error, so I don't include it here, bit it uses a mixin.

The included mixin, called `authGatewayForElements`, has a function called `decryptToken()` and simply decrypt a jwt to get some info. The parameter `userToken` is declared within `data` of this mixin. The function looks like this:

```
decryptToken() {
            let base64Split = this.userToken.split('.')[1];
            let base64 = base64Split.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            let jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));
            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        },
```

Running the test giving me the error **`TypeError: this.userToken.split is not a function`** . I´m new to testing with `vue-test-utils` and maybe or definitely missing something that needs to beincluded in the wrapper, as I expected functions like `split()` don't need to be included additionally.

---

**EDIT:** I get this error on multiple functions, like `find()`, so I'm pretty sure I just do something wrong. Thanks in advance to anybody pointing that out.

Comment: What version of Vue are you using? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 I'm using `vue 3.1.4` with `vue cli 2.9.6` and `vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest 5.0.4`. There are a lot of other dependencies so I can't really recreate the problem in a sandbox. This looks like a general error for something that's been missing. Do you have any idea?